# Where to handle packets between clients?

Tags: linux, security, iptables, firewall

"Server": 192.168.1.1

I want to "theoretically" disable that the clients can "ping" each other.

Can i use an iptables rule for it? e.g.:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.2-192.168.1.255 --dst-range 192.168.1.2-192.168.1.255 -j DROP
```

Is it true that i cannot filter traffic between the clients?? [or at least redirect these packets to e.g.: the router?]

If i run tcpdump on the router ["server"] i can see that a client [192.168.1.201] is pinging another [192.168.1.162]

```
# tcpdump
tcpdump: WARNING: eth0: no IPv4 address assigned
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes
12:22:26.931343 IP 192.168.1.201 > 192.168.1.162: ICMP echo request, id 12547, seq 141, length 64
12:22:27.819373 IP 192.168.1.201 > 192.168.1.162: ICMP echo request, id 12547, seq 142, length 64
12:22:28.819640 IP 192.168.1.201 > 192.168.1.162: ICMP echo request, id 12547, seq 143, length 64
```

Comment: I don't understand your question: it seems to me that the iptables rule you give does what you want. Your tcpdump shows that a client is pinging another client, and that's obviously not something you can prevent on the router; but you seem to have successfully prevented the other client from seeing this ping, what else did you expect? It's also confusing that you sometimes distinguish between “server” and “router”, yet they seem to be the same machine and it's only acting as a router.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you want to disable it? If all traffic runs through a router or switch that can run iptables then yes, it is simple.

If you want to block it on each machine, and they all run iptables, then yes, again - simple.

On most TCP/IP implementations you can disallow ICMP at the client end.

Almost all routers that allow access controls will let you block ICMP.

BUT...are you 100% certain you want to? A lot of apps really like a wee bit of ping to keep em happy :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you have in mind is by all means feasible.  Whether it is good design I can't tell.

Dropping any ICMP echo requests destined for the router:

```
iptables -t filter -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j DROP
```

Dropping any forwarded ICMP echo requests

```
iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -j DROP
```

The reason you see each hosts packets is they are probably connected through a hub, which simply replicates traffic at a lower level.  Dropping those packets on the server will not hinder them from arriving at the clients.

So, in order for the latter rule to work, you'll have to force the hosts forward their entire traffic to the router.  That is done by limiting each host's subnet to its own address (using a subnet mask of 255.255.255.252 for the hosts while sticking to 255.255.255.0 on the router).  Finally, you have to add a static route to each hosts routing table, so he can forward its packets to the server:

```
ip r a 192.168.1.1/32 dev eth0
```

In this setup, the router can still ping all hosts.